# How to overcome the error '.class' expected when declare the datatype in the paranthathesis?

Tags: java

I got the compiler error '.class' expected at the line 14,16 and 18. How to overcome that? Please anybody help me.

filename:DemoClass.java

```java
import java.util.*;

class Visitor extends Thread
{
    String name[] = new String[20];
    String nationality[] = new String[20];
    int age[] = new int[20];
    String a[] = new String[20];
    int i, j = 0;
    int r[] = new int[20];
    int tot[] = new int[20];
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void run()
    {
        getId(int);
        Thread.sleep(3500);
        getData(int);
        Thread.sleep(3500);
        ticketRateCalculating(int);
        Thread.sleep(3500);
    }

    void getId(int no)
    {
        String s1 = "V";
        int k = 1;
        String s2;
        for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
        {
            s2 = s1 + k;
            a[i] = s2;
            k++;
            System.out.println("Your Visitor id is " + a[i]);
        }
    }

    void getData(int no)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("enter the name:");
            name[i] = in .next();
            System.out.println("Enter the age:");
            age[i] = in .nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter the Nationality:");
            nationality[i] = in .next();
        }
    }

    void ticketRateCalculating(int no)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
        {
            if (nationality[i].equals("indian"))
            {
                if (age[i] < 8)
                {
                    r[i] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    r[i] = 20;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (age[i] < 5)
                {
                    r[i] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    r[i] = 50;
                }
            }
            tot[i] = tot[i] + r[i];
        }
    }
}

class Guide extends Visitor implements Runnable
{
    String id[] = new String[20];
    String x;
    int cost[] = new int[20];
    int n;

    public void run()
    {
        guidanceBooking();
        Thread.sleep(2400);
    }

    void guidanceBooking()
    {
        System.out.println("Id            Name      Department   charge");
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        System.out.println("G6        Mr.M.Selvaraj  Zoology       50");
        System.out.println("G7        Ms.S.Jeyapraba Zoology       60");
        System.out.println("G1        Ms.T.kavitha   Archeology    70");
        System.out.println("G8        Mr.S.Sivaraman Botony        50");
        System.out.println("G3        Ms.R.Anusri    Antropology   80");
        System.out.println("G5        Ms.S.praneetha Antropology   60");
        System.out.println("G4        Ms.V.kavitha   Botony        60");
        System.out.println("G2        Mr.S.Ram       Archeology    50");
        System.out.println("enter the number of guides do you want?:");

        n = in .nextInt();

        System.out.println("enter the Guidance id:");

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            id[i] = in .next();
        }

        System.out.println("Booked Guide's id:");

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(id[i]);
            System.out.println("");
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (id[i].equals("G6") || id[i].equals("G8") || id[i].equals("G2"))
            {
                j = 50;
                tot[i] += j;
            }
            else if (id[i].equals("G7") || id[i].equals("G5") || id[i].equals("G4"))
            {
                j = 60;
                tot[i] += j;
            }
            else if (id[i].equals("G1"))
            {
                j = 70;
                tot[i] += j;
            }
            else
            {
                j = 80;
                tot[i] += j;
            }
        }
    }

    void login(int no)
    {
        int total;
        System.out.println("enter the Visitor id:");
        x = in .next();
        for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
        {
            if (a[i].equals(x))
            {
                System.out.println("Name:" + name[i]);
                System.out.println("Age:" + age[i]);
                System.out.println("Nationality:" + nationality[i]);
                System.out.println("Guidance charge:" + j);
                System.out.println("Total cost:" + tot[i]);
                System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry,Your Visitor id isn't valid!");
            }
        }
    }
}

class DemoClass
{
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        int ch, n, c;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Guide g = new Guide();
        g.start();
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(date.toString());
        System.out.println("Enter the number of tickets do you want?");
        n = in .nextInt();
        do
        {
            System.out.println("1.Register 2.Login");
            System.out.println("Enter the choice:");
            ch = in .nextInt();
            switch (ch)
            {
                case 1:
                    g.getData(n);
                    g.ticketRateCalculating(n);
                    g.getId(n);
                    System.out.println("Do You want guide?(0/1)");
                    System.out.println("Enter 0 for yes and 1 for no:");
                    c = in .nextInt();
                    if (c == 0)
                    {
                        g.guidanceBooking();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    g.login(n);
                    break;
            }
        } while (ch <= 2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
D:\16it053>javac DemoClass.java

DemoClass.java:14: error: '.class' expected

        getId(int);
                 ^
DemoClass.java:16: error: '.class' expected

       getData(int);
                  ^
DemoClass.java:18: error: '.class' expected

       ticketRateCalculating(int);
                                ^
3 errors
```

Comment: Downvoted for way too much code.  And the code is not formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `getId` expects an `int` value:

```java
void getId(int no)
{
    // ...
}
```

But you call it with the `int` primitive type:

```java
getId(int);
```

Please call `getId`, `getData` and `ticketRateCalculating` with an `int` value, like any of these:

```java
int no = 1;
getId(no);
getData(2);
ticketRateCalculating(no+2);
```